# Overriding content security policy that has been set by HTML meta tag

Tags: testing, content-security-policy, meta-tags

I want to test a local script that makes a call to a third party script (testing a SAAS app). However, I'm being blocked by the CSP policy as my domain is not in the directives.

The CSP is set by a meta HTML tag with `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"`

How do I bypass these policies. I have tried multiple extensions and failed.

Example Meta Tag

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.braintreegateway.com *.paypalobjects.com  *.paypal.com *.googlecommerce.com  https://*.screenpopper.com screenpopper.com
*.google.com *.facebook.com *.facebook.net *.bing.com *.criteo.net *.google-analytics.com https://*.acsbap.com
*.doubleclick.net *.criteo.com *.nr-data.net https://cdn.ywxi.net *.mcafeesecure.com  *.googleapis.com *.klevu.com https://static.klaviyo.com/ https://static-tracking.klaviyo.com/ https://*.gorgias.chat/ https://polyfill.io/
*.gstatic.com *.youtube.com *.emailage.com *.googleadservices.com *.googletagmanager.com *.oraclecloud.com
*.trustlogo.com  *.trustedsite.com  https://www.clickcease.com
secure.comodo.com *.criteo.com *.bbb.org  *.newrelic.com *.callrail.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/  https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/
https://*.amazon.com https://static-na.payments-amazon.com https://*.amazonpay.com *.rtb123.com
https://*.cloudfront.net https://widget.trustpilot.com https://*.getbread.com https://*.digicert.com  https://*.inspectlet.com https://*.fontawesome.com;

form-action 'self' *.paypal.com sandbox.paypal.com https://*.amazon.com https://cdn.ywxi.net *.facebook.com;

frame-src 'self' *.google.com https://*.accessibe.com *.facebook.com *.paypalobjects.com https://acsbapp.com https://*.acsbapp.com https://acsbap.com https://player.vimeo.com/ *.braintreegateway.com
 https://widget.trustpilot.com https://*.paypal.com/ *.trustedsite.com https://cdn.ywxi.net https://bid.g.doubleclick.net
 https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ https://www.youtube.com/ *.amazon.com *.getbread.com *.payments-amazon.com ;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Security Policy is a security mechanism not meant to be bypassed. Adding another policy will only make the total enforced policy stricter. You might need to rewrite the content, e.g. by a proxy or check if CSP enforcement can be disabled in the browser.

Comment: You can set up a proxy that just forwards requests/responses and adds/removes headers.

Comment: Ok you are correct -  I used an desktop app that used a MITM proxy that allowed me to edit the response body and I updated the directives with the domain for the app that was being blocked.  Although I could have just removed the meta HTML tag altogether.